# How can I get DrawGeometry to draw along device pixel lines in WPF?

Tags: wpf, drawingcontext

I'm trying to use `DrawingContext.DrawGeometry` get a rectangle with 1 device pixel wide sides.

```
var geometry = (defined elsewhere from a Rect {0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 18.0})
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff));

// Note: the pen is declared with a 1.0 thickness
var pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)), 1.0)

drawingContext.DrawGeometry(brush, pen, geometry);
```

I have verified that the `Rect` I'm building the geometry with is whole numbers, not fractional points (manually verified), and the `Pen` I'm drawing the geometry with is `1.0` units wide.

The problem is that the rect is being drawn on screen 2 device pixels wide. How can I draw this rectangle on exact device pixels? I'm expecting that at 96dpi, this will come out to 1 pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DrawingContext.PushGuidelineSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pushguidelineset.aspx) to force the rendering to align when possible.

For details and sample code, see [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html).

Comment: It's a little awkward, since now I have to look at the individual rects that make up the geometry, but it does work. Good tip, thanks.